# Retaining File names when using Fine Uploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm trying to implement the Fine Uploader for the first time and have a question. I've got the uploader pushing files to my S3 bucket. The issue I have is the file is being renamed to some sort of string.

Here's an example: 4f65aefe-c55b-42b0-afd4-b749c755e7e8.zip

I'd like to keep the original file name if possible. Is that possible?

Here is the script on the page with my current set of params:

```
var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById("fineUploader"),
    request: {
        endpoint: "mybucket.amazonaws.com",
        accessKey: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"
    },
    signature: {
        endpoint: "/wp-content/themes/zone/vendor/fineuploader/php-s3-server/endpoint.php"
    },
    iframeSupport: {
        localBlankPagePath: "/wp-content/themes/zone/success.html"
    },
    cors: {
        expected: true
    },
    chunking: {
        enabled: true
    },
    resume: {
        enabled: true
    },
});
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. By default, Fine Uploader S3 will use a UUID to name your object when sending it to an S3 bucket. In almost all cases, this is the *safest* behavior. If you change this value, you run the risk of overwriting existing files with new ones in the event of a name collision. The object is annotated with the original file name attached to an "x-amz-meta-qqfilename" header.

If you must save the object in S3 using a different name, you can modify the `objectProperties.key` option appropriately. A value of "filename" will save the object using the original filename. You can also set the value to a function where you can determine the name on-demand, even using values from some other location, provided your key function returns a Promise. Read more about this option at http://docs.fineuploader.com/api/options-s3.html#objectProperties.key.